# find -type d and ls return different results on same directory

Tags: find, ubuntu-16.04, ls, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to think of a reason find would return partial results on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a google drive mount (using [plexdrive](https://github.com/dweidenfeld/plexdrive)) located at
    /home/user/media

When using

```
find $HOME/media -type d
```

16 results are returned. When using

```
ls -d $HOME/media/*/
```

186 results are returned. The folders are all browsable via sftp and samba shares, all permissions on relevant directories are 775. The content in the media directory is formatted as

```
a/a.ext
b/b.ext
c/c.ext
```

Has anyone seen this type of behavior before or have any clues on how to get find to return the full results?

Comment: ls would display all files not only folders...

Comment: Sorry `ls -d $HOME/media/*` is the actual command. I've edited the original post.

Comment: To add to this, `find` works great elsewhere on my system, so I'm thinking this may be more of a bug in plexdrive than anything else.

Comment: `ls -d` will still display both files and folders...

Comment: It doesn't on my system, ubuntu 16.04 server, and [-d is the flag for directories only](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls), so I'm not sure why you think it would show files. Either way, that's irrelevant. The goal here is to find out why `find` isn't returning full results.

Comment: again I insist `ls -d` will show files as well.. you can easily test it... `cd` to any directory with files and directories... and then do `ls *` and `ls -d *`... what `-d` does is if a directory is found while expanding the glob, it will show only directory name instead of showing contents of those directories as well... if a file is found while using `ls -d` it will be displayed as well... `find -type d` obviously won't show files

Comment: While that may be true, there are no files in the directory I'm scanning, only other subdirectories containing files, so the flags are a moot point. It's also possible to add a trailing slash so only directories match `ls -d */`.

Comment: if `ls -d $HOME/media/*/` and `ls -d $HOME/media/*` are returning same number of results, then all the directories inside `$HOME/media` are empty?

Comment: The -d flag stops `ls` from listing the contents of directories. The only files included would be ones existing in the directory defined in the command. There are no files in `$HOME/media/`, only directories. `ls -d $HOME/media/*/` and `ls -d $HOME/media/*` do indeed return the exact same number of results and every single subdirectory has content.

Comment: oh okay, got it.. I hadn't considered that possibility... in any case, am glad that you solved the issue yourself :)

Comment: Yes, I'm glad it's solved too; and hopefully, this helps someone in the future. Thank you for the attention, and for explaining `ls` in further detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when `find` is looking at a directory with symbolic links. Use the -L flag to see the proper folder structure. `find -L $HOME/media -type d`